# gcloud components update crashes when updating to 224.0.0

Tags: gcloud

When running "gcloud components update" or "gcloud components list", it crashes with the error message: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 30):

If you see this error, it is most likely that you installed the `container-builder-local` component. The crash is because this component was removed in version 224.0.0 and replaced with `cloud-build-local`.

So the work-around is:

1. remove container-builder-local: `gcloud components remove container-builder-local`
2. update: `gcloud components update`
3. install cloud-build-local: `gcloud components install cloud-build-local`

Comment: this saved me! Thanks!

Comment: It also happen for older versions `210.0.0`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently on gcloud v222.0.0 and ran into the error:
`ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'` when trying to update components.

I can confirm that removing `container-build-local` and updating to `cloud-build-local` fixes this error.

```
Installing components from version: 224.0.0

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│         These components will be installed.          │
├──────────────────────────────────┬─────────┬─────────┤
│               Name               │ Version │   Size  │
├──────────────────────────────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ Google Cloud Build Local Builder │   0.4.2 │ 5.9 MiB │
│ Google Cloud Build Local Builder │         │         │
└──────────────────────────────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

I was caught unaware of this breaking change